# Routing not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

There are regular pages on the site such as:

```
foo.com/about
foo.com/contact
```

I use single controller for these.

There is also pages for admin, i have a seperate controller:
    foo.com/admin/createsomething

This is my routing config and it is not picking HomeController Actions.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Admin",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: tested it.it is working without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need routes for the urls that break the default convention:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "About",
    url: "about",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Contact",
    url: "contact",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

then your admin url should resolve with the default route, where you have an `AdminController` and a `CreateSomething` action method